# is it possible to set number of colums different for diffrent rows of a grid view?

Tags: android, gridview

my perpose is to set headers for related items of  griv view and for this i am thinking about to set the width of gridview diffrent for header and sectional view's .......

if any other way 2 set sectional header for related items is possible ???

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to set number of colums different for diffrent rows of a grid view ??

No, sorry.

> if any other way 2 set sectional header for related items is possible ???

In theory, sections in a `GridView` should be no different than sections in a `ListView`. You need a custom `Adapter` that knows about the sections and returns appropriate `Views` for those section headings, along with the actual data.

That being said, I have never seen a `GridView` with section headings, so I do not know how well it will work.

Comment: it is possible to set the number of colums different for diffrent rows of a grid view check my answer

Comment: @StefanBossbaly ... I am looking to do the same and cannot find your answer